# How to automatically redirect on access denied errors (401) in IIS?

Tags: iis, http-error-401.2, iis-10

I have the following issue with a Web Site deployed within IIS:

The web site uses Windows Authentication only and the domain controller serving the application is not stable. Due to configuration issues (no redundant DC configured), the application fails to authenticate the users (401).

Any trials for redirection at `web.config` (e.g. `customErrors` with redirect) and I think this is due to access denied being issues by IIS (tries to validate the security ticket, fails to find a domain controller and asks for credentials before anything related to the application itself is processed).

**Question:** Is is possible to configure IIS to automatically redirect requests, if it fails to authenticate them?

Note: I have a failover web server that works, but the load balancing is not done yet, that's why I want to make the redirection like this.

Comment: I am using IIS 10 (tried to add as tag, but I do not have the required 300points to create it).

Comment: Maybe fix the actual problem rather than a symptom of the problem?

Comment: @joeqwerty - Unfortunately, I do not have the power to fix the actual problem. I have investigate it and I have e-mailed the appropriate persons investigation results (i.e. domain controllers are properly configured, so that if one fails, there is no other configured to process the requests). I am trying to fix what is possible until I manage to fight through bureaucracy.

Comment: In IIS 6 & 7 you could create custom error pages for 401/404 (and other) errors. I assume there must be a similar facility in 10 ?  (Also title says 404 but Q says 401)